# ionic app promise only works in first view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building a simple news app.

It has two views.

One is the list of stories, and the other is the list of categories.  Each one has an `http.jsonp` request.

The problem is, only the first view loaded's controller will get a promise returned.  For example, if I load the story list view first (in otherwords load page #home in my browser), the http.jsonp request comes fine and I see my "back from stories promise" alert.  Then, when I click the tab button to switch to the category view, I see my http.jsonp request and the data returned, so the controller ang getCats() must be called, but it doesn't return the promise - I never see the "back from getCats promise" alert.  If I use the exact same code but start by loading the category view in the browser first, then the categories populate fine but when I switch to the story view, it again doesn't return the promise.  So, it seems to be related to switching to the second view within the app.

How can I get the second view to return the promise?

```
app.controller('listCtrl', ['$q','$scope','$state', 'StoriesFact',
    function($q, $scope, $state, StoriesFact){

        StoriesFact.getStories($scope).then(function(response){
            alert("back from stories promise");
            $scope.stories = response;
        });


}]);


app.controller('sectionCtrl', ['$scope', 'StoriesFact',
    function($scope, StoriesFact){

        StoriesFact.getCats().then(function(response){
            alert("back from getCats promise");
            $scope.categories = response;
        });


}]);
```

And here is my factory with the actual http calls:

```
angular.module('reader.StoriesFact', [])

.factory('StoriesFact', function($http, $q, $state) {

    return {
        getCats: function() {  
            var q = $q.defer();

            jsonURL = 'http://www.bendbulletin.com/somejson?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&pub=BendBulletin';

            $http.jsonp(jsonURL)
                .success(function(data) {
                    q.resolve(data.categories);
                }); 
            return q.promise;
        },
        getStories: function() {
            var q = $q.defer();

            jsonURL2 = 'http://www.bendbulletin.com/somejson?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&cats=1829480:1829507:1829469';

            $http.jsonp(jsonURL2)
                .success(function(data) {
                    q.resolve(data.stories);
                });
            return q.promise;
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: You can use  $ionicView.enter in this situation. (This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached view.)

Comment: So, not really an answer exactly but I went another route.  I stopped using jsonp and am just using a simple $http.get.  This does return the promise.  Doing a bit more reading I found out that apps don't have to deal with Cors issues?  So I am okay with using the get.  Is that true?

Comment: In a Ajax call you always have to deal with Cors. XmlHttpRequest is different than HttpRequest. In the former case cors is requiered at least as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I changed one of the factory functions - getStories to a plain http.get and now it seems to work.  I got rid of any of my own promise code - $q library, and just used the promise that the http request returns for the getCats call.  I had to change the factory to call it differently however.

```
    return {
        getCats: function() {  
            jsonURL = 'http://www.bendbulletin.com/somejson?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&pub=BendBulletin';

            return $http.jsonp(jsonURL).then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });

        },
        getStories: function() {  
            jsonURL = 'http://www.bendbulletin.com/somejson?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&pub=BendBulletin';

            return $http.get(jsonURL).then(function(response){
                appCats = response.data;
                return response.data;
            });
```

I changed nothing in the controller and now my promise is returned for both.  Im thinking that only one type of promise can return to a single view?